# Would you say this phrase in bentsching while eating at a gentile’s house?

Tags: gentiles, bentching

Someone ate their own kosher meal at a gentile’s house. Would they still say the following phrase?

> הָרַחֲמָן הוּא יִשְׁלַח לָנוּ בְּרָכָה מְרֻבָּה בַּבַּיִת הַזֶּה, וְעַל שֻׁלְחָן זֶה שֶׁאָכַלְנוּ עָלָיו.‏
>
> May the All-merciful send a plentiful blessing upon this house, and upon this table at which we have eaten.

I'm concerned, because usually we don't praise gentiles ([see Yoreh Deah 151:14](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%93)).

Comment: Shouldn't the translation be more like: "May the All-merciful send _us_ a plentiful blessing _in_ this house, and upon this table at which we have eaten"?

Comment: @Tamir Discuss it with Sefaria...

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer at [Hidabroot](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/236923) which credits the source as the sefer "לחיות כהלכה - הלכות מצויות שאינן ידועות כל כך" I do not see an author.

---

Question: If one eats in a place that belongs to a non-Jew, does one say “harachaman hu yishlach lanu bracha meruba babayit hazeh v’al shulchan zeh she’achalnu alav?”

Answer: No because of the issur of [לא תחנם](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D). Instead you should say, “May the All-Merciful send us a plentiful blessing on our journeying and resting for ever.”

Amongst other sources, he quotes Mishna Berura 193 [27].

> **שאלה:** האוכל במקום השייך לגוי, האם יאמר בברכת המזון: הרחמן הוא ישלח לנו ברכה מרובה בבית הזה ועל שולחן זה שאכלנו עליו?
>
> **תשובה:** לא יאמר הרחמן זה [* כיון שאסור לברך גוי משום לא תחנם], ובמקומו יאמר: הרחמן הוא ישלח לנו ברכה מרובה בהליכתנו ובישיבתנו עד עולם.